# Error 53 network path not found Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares, shared-folders

I want to access a shared folder on a network. I was able to share data through this folder two days ago. Now, when I double click the folder on workstation, I have error message

```
network path not found
```

With command prompt, and `net view \\<IP_address for the shared folder>`

I have this error

```
system error 53 has occurred

the network path was not found
```

I allowed this IP address in running windows firewall, no result.

How could i fix that, where can the problem come from?

Comment: Does the computer with shared folder obtain IP-address from DHCP-server?

Comment: How to obtain IP address from DHCP server ? thanks

Comment: Do you have a router which assigns IP-addresses automatically?
Most likely you shared a folder, then turned OFF your pc/laptop, turn it on, and IP was changed.